# Which one gets loaded first? static block or spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, static

I am autowiring an object of with spring and I am calling a method using the same autowired object. It is throwing NullPointerException. The problem is that I am calling the method inside a static block. Below is my code -

```
@Autowired
static MyPropertyManagerClass myPropertyManagerClass;

private static URL SERVICE_URL = null;

static {
    try {

        SERVICE_URL = myPropertyManagerClass.getServiceURL();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred While Invoking myPropertyManagerClass.getServiceURL() : " , e);
    }
}
```

If I am not wrong, this is happening because static block gets loaded first. Is there any way that I can make this work without creating an object with new keyword?

Comment: Use @PostConstruct and put your code there. PostConstruct will be called when all your dependencies are initialized

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*static blocks* are invoked when the class is being initialized, after it is loaded. The dependencies of your *component* haven't been initialized yet. That is why you get a `NullPointerException` (Your dependencies are null) .

Move your code to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. This will ensure that your code will run when all the dependencies of your component are initialized

Comment: Does `@PostConstruct` block is executed after all the beans are injected or after the current bean class gets injected. In other words, Can I place my `@PostConstruct` in any other non-component class (which is not loaded by spring at all) ? @TheLostMind

Comment: @RishavSharan - PostConstruct gets executed after all the "dependencies" of "your component" have been initialized. PostConstruct is a Java annotation hence it should be called after dependency injection . It will be executed even if the class does not request any resources to be injected.

Comment: static keyword execute only 1 time and @PostConstruct executes depends on how many times object initialized( no of times it executes).

Answer (score 6):

`static` block will always be processed before the spring injection. As suggested by @TheLostMind, *"Use `@PostConstruct` and put your code there"*. 
If you want to avoid the `new` you can use the spring `factory-method` in your Xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Static would be first.
Spring beans would be initialized after BeanPostProcessor initialize level.